# How to set state in react hooks only if state is different from current value

Tags: reactjs, request, react-hooks

I have the following code

```
setInterval(() => {
             fetch(`/clusters?type=${type}`)
                .then((response) => response.json()
                  .then((responseBody) => {
                    if(clusters !== responseBody.members)
                        setClusters(responseBody.members);
                  }))
                .catch();
    }, 5000);
```

Since `clusters` is set asynchronously when check `if(clusters !== responseBody.members)` `clusters` is always empty so which is right way to do it? I'm trying to do it in order to have less renders since that request happens every 5 seconds

Comment: It shouldn't cause a re-render if the data hasn't changed. ReactJS is smart enough to only render if there's a diff.

Answer (score 2):

That is because the state you're getting is stale already. What you can do is create a ref using `useRef` and then inside another `useEffect` just update the ref with the current value of your state. And then after fetching the data use ref to compare it to the state, like this:

```js
function App() {
  const [clusters, setClusters] = useState([]);
  const clustersRef = useRef(clusters);

  useEffect(() => {
    clustersRef.current = clusters;
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => {
      fetch(`/clusters?type=${type}`)
      .then((response) => response.json()
      .then((responseBody) => {
          if(clustersRef.current !== responseBody.members)
            setClusters(responseBody.members);
      }))
      .catch();
    }, 5000);
  }, []);
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: did not work, as @AlexWayne said `[1,2,3] !== [1,2,3] //-> true`

Comment: Yeah my bad, you cannot compare arrays like that, so to compare them you make strings of their ids and then compare them, or maybe the length of those arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a function to `setClusters` that gets the current state as an argument. Then you can compare and either return the new items if there is something new, or the old value if nothing has changed. React is smart enough to know that it should not re-render if you set state to the *exact* same value.

But you have another problem. React is already smart enough not to re-render if your state hasn't changed. But your state *is* changing. Your api call is creating new data objects that will not be directly comparable to your old ones.

So, you need to figure out a better way to detect if something has changed. The `===` or `!==` wont tell you have two arrays have the same items, they will tell you if they are the same exact instance of array.

```
[1,2,3] === [1,2,3] //-> false
```

So you have to come up with a way to tell if you have two arrays contain the same content. One way to do that is to create a string of ids from the old and new data and then compare those. (Assuming `clusters` is an array of objects that have some uniq `id` on them). You create a single value that can be compared to another single value to see if anything has changed.

```
setClusters(prevClusters => {
  const prevIds = prevClusters.map(member => member.id).sort().join('-')
  const newIds = responseBody.members.map(member => member.id).sort().join('-')

  if (newIds === prevIds) {
    return prevClusters // nothing has changed, return previous value
  } else {
    return responseBody.members // return new values.
  }
})
```

Comment: Then it's up to you to come up with a simple algorithm that can tell you if you have the same data. I couldn't possibly know your data model.